# Migrate Wordpress to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress

My company has been using Squarespace for domain+hosting.

I've been trying to move away from it, so I set up a webserver with Wordpress and built the new website we'll be using.

I want to now transfer the Squarespace domain, and transfer the Wordpress site to AWS and then connect the two so that when people go to the domain it shows the wordpress site.. and I'd need to do this with as little downtime as possible.

I'm in the process of transferring the domain to Route 53.. this should be okay.

My real concern/question is how should I transfer my already existing Wordpress site to AWS, and then connecting it to the domain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Elasticbeanstalk has a pre-baked deployment for PHP applications:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html

Elasticbeanstalk basically manages the AWS hosting/DB resources for you, allowing you to simply upload your code.

You would have to import your existing DB into this setup, but that's relatively straightforward.